# Mockito not mocking field of mocked object

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a service class that looks like this:

```
public class MyServiceClassImpl implements MyServiceClass {

  private final MyRepository myRepository;

  private final EntityDTOConverter entityConverter;

...
}
```

Where EntityDTOConverter is a bean to convert entity to DTO and vice-versa. It uses a ModelMapper like this:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EntityDTOConverter {

  private final ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
...
}
```

Then I'm trying to test the service like this:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyServiceClassImplTest {

  @InjectMocks
  private MyServiceClassImpl myServiceClass;

  @Mock
  private MyRepository myRepository;

  @Mock
  private EntityDTOConverter entityConverter;

  private Entity myEntity;

  private EntityDTO myEntityDTO;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setUp() {
    myEntityDTO = new EntityDTO();

    myEntity = Entity.newInstance("name", "surname", "email@email.com");
    myEntity.setId(randomUUID());

    lenient().when(myRepository.save(myEntity)).thenReturn(myEntity);
    lenient().when(entityConverter.convert(any(EntityDTO.class))).thenReturn(myEntity);
  }
```

Basically I'm trying to set that any DTO that goes through the converter should be converted properly. But this is there I get the error. When it tries to mock the entityConverter.convert() method, it's actually making a call to the method. The method then uses the modelMapper, which in this mock is **null**. The modelMapper is initialized directly in the class, as posted above (although I've also tried to make it a bean in the app context and inject it but the result was the same):

[image: null modelMapper]

This then results in an NPE when the test is being ran. How should I fix it?

Comment: The `EntityDTOConverter` is being mocked as expected. I assume something in the test's setup is missing. If you post the actual code that's being tested it'd be easier to tell what's going on (my guess is that you probably need to mock the `ModelMapper`).

Answer (score 3):

Mockito cannot breake the rules of Java. That includes that it cannot change the execution order of a specific line of code. Therefore the line

```
   lenient().when(entityConverter.convert(any(EntityDTO.class))).thenReturn(myEntity);
```

must first execute the `convert()` method in your real `EntityDTOConverter` class. Since the current instance of `EntityDTOConverter` class is a mock created by *Mockito* its fields are initialized with `null`. So if the method `convert()` accesses such a property a NPE is thrown.

The solution for this problem is to use the other form to configure the mock:

```
doReturn(myEntity)
   .when(entityConverter).convert(any(EntityDTO.class))
// take care for the different positions of closing braces!
```

This way the mock (which is basically an extension of your real class) intercepts the call to  `convert()` so that your real code in this method is not executed and no NPE is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

If mockito was actually mocking the `convert` method it wouldn't be trying to to access the modelMapper. You can try removing the exact requirement of the inserted class (e.g. `entityConverter.convert(any())`).

Side point - I don't think overusing *lenient* is a good practice so you might want to drop that unless it's really necessary.

Comment: I agree on the *lenient* part. It has been added for a good reason to Mockito, and it has a specific meaning. Don't over use it. Instead, think about its meaning. Baeldung has got a good article on it : https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-unnecessary-stubbing-exception

Comment: No worries about the lenient(). I was actually just playing with it because I got into this error, was not planning to stick with it in the final code once the error was fixed.